# Tempdb Splitting File/Filegroups among different Databases

Tags: sql-server, performance, tempdb, filegroups, performance-tuning

A common problem placing databases on one server Instance is they all share same tempdb. Is it possible to allocate tempdb file/and filegroups for separate databases. Does Resource Governor allow this?

Database 1, only gets access to one file/filegroup 1 in tempdb.

Database 2, only gets access to one file/filegroup 2 in tempdb.

Comment: How is that a problem?

Comment: Put your tempdb on fast solid state disks; you'll be fine at any reasonable size of a few terabytes or less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Resource Governor is for throttling CPU, query workspace memory, and storage throughput, but there is no feature in SQL Server that restricts which files/filegroups a database can access in TempDB.

Plus, think about cross-database queries - if you had a cross-database query, how would that even work?

Answer (score 2):

If you need that level of granularity, you should setup multiple SQL Server instances; that is the only way to have multiple tempdb databases.